# Criar arrays dentro do while

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  $urls = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=teste'); // teste é a palavra que vai pesquisar no google

    preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com.br/i', $urls, $content); // filtra apenas as urls .com.br da pagina

    $i = 10; // inicia do 10

    while ( $i <= 50 ) { // o while vai entrar nas paginas da paginação, 50 quer dizer até a pagina 5 da paginação, pois cada pagina exibe 10 resultados

    $i+= 10;

    $urls2 = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=teste&start=".$i."'); // start é onde vai iniciar na proxima pagina (paginação dos resultados da pesquisa)

    preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com/i', $urls2, $contentLoop);

    $totalArray = array_merge($content,$contentLoop);


    }

    print_r($totalArray);
```

Dentro do while o preg_match_all em cada volta cria um array diferente já que o file_get_contents tbm é alterado de acordo com a paginação (por causa do $i na url).

Como faço para dentro da variavel $totalArray ter um unico array com todos arrays capturados durante o loop e acessar a variavel $totalArray fora do loop?

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: por favor, edite sua pergunta colocando o `array` que está sendo gerado nesse momento, e um modelo do que você espera.

Answer (score 2):

Um array multidimensional?

Pode ser apenas isso:

```
$totalArray[] = $contentLoop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=teste'); // teste é a palavra que vai pesquisar no google

preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com.br/i', $urls, $content); // filtra apenas as urls .com.br da pagina

$i = 10; // inicia do 10

$totalArray = $content;

while ( $i <= 50 ) { // o while vai entrar nas paginas da paginação, 50 quer dizer até a pagina 5 da paginação, pois cada pagina exibe 10 resultados

$i+= 10;

$urls2 = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=teste&start=".$i."'); // start é onde vai iniciar na proxima pagina (paginação dos resultados da pesquisa)

preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com/i', $urls2, $contentLoop);

$totalArray = array_merge($totalArray,$contentLoop);


}

print_r($totalArray);
```

Comment: Obrigada, mas o resultado é o mesmo ainda